# Lombok log variable not found when running Junit

Tags: spring-boot, junit, lombok

I am using Lombok for logging in my project. I have installed the Lombok plugin in IntelliJ and enabled Annotation processing. Now it do not show any errors in the source code. But when I run my Junit test, compiling is failing because it is not able to find *log* variable.

Following line in the class under test is causing error

```
log.info("Request received at /v1/employees");
```

What else do I need to do to support Lombok for unit tests?

Comment: Could you share the code snippet of your junit test where you are getting the compilation issue?

Comment: Logging that is causing the issue is not in Junit but in the class under test.

Comment: “ log.info(...) “ It seems like you need log4j dependency in your modules. I am wondering how you are using Lombok for logging

Comment: Well Lombok takes care of the dependencies as per the  logging specific library annotation.

Comment: Then i guess you would be missing the following dependency - <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>